# Loading user roles from different source while using Spring Azure OAuth

Tags: spring, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

We are developing Spring app and we have decided to use Azure OAuth as authentication method. The problem is that the we do not want to store roles in AAD. We would like to use AAD just to confirm user identity and load the rest of data (like roles) from other source. Is this possible? What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found a solution, I can write a custom method for @PreAuthorize: https://dreamix.eu/blog/java/implementing-custom-authorization-function-for-springs-pre-and-post-annotations